# STM32 GSM AT command response parser

Tags: stm32, at-command, gprs

I am sending AT command to get IMEI no.

```
char CGSN[] = "AT+CGSN\r\n";

// in while loop 
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,(uint8_t *)CGSN, sizeof(CGSN),100);
HAL_Delay(1000);    
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t *)&ch,1);  

// Callback 
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  if(huart->Instance == USART2){
    if(buf[i]!=13){
      buf[i]=ch;
      i++;
    } 

  }
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t *)&ch,1);

  buf[i]=0;
}
```

the response stored in buffer is - `\r\n9876543212345\r\n\r\nOK\r\n`
What is best way to receive response and filter out n"9876543212345" & "OK" and store separately in a array to further process

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use sscanf for this purpose. Below is the quick implementation of the scenario in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long a;
    char array[10];
    char string[] = "\r\n9876543212345\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
    sscanf(string , "\r\n%ld\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", &a, array);
    printf("%ld %s\n", a, array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sluhana, i have tried sscanf and strtok but not able to get desired result , i was just looking at simple method to store both in two separate array Eg: array1[]="9876543212345" & array2[]="OK"

Comment: why exactly it fails with sscanf? I understand you are working with a controller with limited amount of memory. I once faced such a issue, I was facing a stack overflow issue in my case.

Comment: finally made it work using sscanf, but now have some more challenges, will keep you update, thanks again

Comment: got into new issue with sscanf, if i pass buffer[]="AT+CGSN\r\n9876543212345\r\n\r\nOK\r\n" and n=sscanf(buffer,%s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n%s\r\n",header,result,response); returns 3 which is ok. Now in my program flow buffer stores data from a call back function and is filled with same "AT+CGSN\r\n9876543212345\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", but sscanf return only 1, it only scans the first string, any suggestion on how to solve this ?

Comment: there is a null '\0' present in the buffer[]="AT+CGSN\r\n\0\r\n9876543212345\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", may be that's terminating the sscanf, not able to remove '\0' from the array

Answer (score 0):

Problem is simple! Your buf[] dont include *'\r'*  (in decimal 13).
Correct value buf[] is *"AT+CGSN\n9876543212345\n\nOK\n\0"*.